# What is the equivalent of String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I would like to know what is equivalent of Swift's `String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue`.

I need this for proper encoding of string value.

Comment: you need swift code or Objective C code ?

Comment: you mean `NSUTF8StringEncoding`?

Comment: need to convert string to Data right ?

Comment: use `NSUTF8StringEncoding` in objective C

Comment: I am looking for Objective C code

Comment: @Ronak, I would like to know how to use that rawValue in objective-c

Comment: @vedhanish `NSUTF8StringEncoding` in Objective-C is an integer value equivalent to `String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue`

Comment: `code`let mToken = dataForToken.data(using:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
`code`let plainData = mToken as! NSData

This is the code that I would like to convert to Objective C

Comment: Thanks ltai Ferber. I got it working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift code:

```
func swiftDataToString(someData:Data) -> String? {
    return String(data: someData, encoding: .utf8)
}

func swiftStringToData(someStr:String) ->Data? {
    return someStr.data(using: .utf8)
}
```

Obj-C equivalents:

```
    -(NSString *) objCDataToString:(NSData *)someData {
    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:someData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}


-(NSData *) objCStringToData:(NSString *)someString {
    return [someString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

Using your variable name, the code you are looking for is:

```
-(NSData *) dataFor:(NSString *)token {
    return [token dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

Comment: This approach helped me to implement my functionality.